# Dereferencing volatile pointers for memory-mapped registers

Tags: c, reference, volatile

I infrequently use volatile pointers to access memory-mapped registers on embedded systems. These registers are typically used to read from/control peripherals.

Here is an example of such use:

```
volatile uint32_t * p_reg = (volatile uint32_t *) 0x2800L;

uint32_t value = *p_reg ; // read register
*p_reg = 1; // write register
```

Is it possible declare and use the registers as a value (e.g. `volatile uint_32 reg`) rather than a pointer? Litteraly every examples I found use pointers for memory-mapped registers.

Comment: none that I can think of. If the register you want is at address 0x2800, you'd need to somehow enforce your program to compile your `uint_32 reg` variable at that address. If there's a way to do that I don't know it. What's wrong with pointers?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, this is just curiosity. Wouldn't `volatile uint32_t reg = *p_reg` work?

Comment: The declaration and initialization `volatile uint32_t reg = *p_reg;` would work at the time the initialization is executed, but thereafter `reg` would not reflect what's currently in the register.

Comment: Is there any use-case for using volatile not on pointers?

Comment: Not in standard C. You may be able to use linker options to place a particular section at a specific address.